# EasyMock with EasyMockSupport: cannot use mocks in @Before

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I would like to set some common expectations on my timeServiceMock, but it is still null in before method. Any way to make it work without need to call before() in every test?

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest extends EasyMockSupport {

  ...@TestSubject and so on

  @Mock
  private TimeService timeServiceMock;

  @Before
  public void before() {

    System.out.println(this.timeServiceMock);
  }

   ...tests
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EasyMockRunner only creates and injects mocks in @Test.

so if you want to use it in a @Before, remove the @Mock annotation from `TimeService` and create the mock yourself in @Before.  Then you will have to inject the mock yourself into the @TestSubject.

So something like this:

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest extends EasyMockSupport {

  @TestSubject and so on
  Foo testSubject = ...

  private TimeService timeServiceMock;

  @Before
  public void before() {
   this.timeServiceMock = createMock(TimeService.class);
    ...
  }

   @Test
   public void mytest(){
     testSubject.setTimeService(timeServiceMock);
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly the stuff you would like to remove from my code by using EasyMockSupport...